# How long is the tag T in AES-GCM(Or: Can implementations freely choose t = len(T)?)

Tags: aes, tls, authenticated-encryption, gcm

I've started to learn about GCM. In the [paper](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/gcm/gcm-spec.pdf) I read on page 4 there is the equation:
$$
T = \text{MSB}_t(\text{GHASH}(H, A, C) \oplus E(K, Y_0))
$$

It's clear to me that the function $\text{MSB}_t(S)$ returns the bit string containing only the most significant (leftmost) $t$ bits of $S$ (defined on the same page).
But I couldn't find any info on the value of $t$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Security) mentions several possible sizes of $t$ with advantages and disadvantages.

So, can the implementer choose $t$?

Which value of $t$ is used in TLS's AES-GCM cipher suites?

EDIT: [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26726/can-i-reduce-the-mac-size-in-tls) I can see that [RFC 5116](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5116) is determining $t = 128$, but how can I see that [RFC 5116](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5116) is part of TLS 1.2?

Comment: The above is a broader question, but I believe the answer there answers all your questions as well?

Comment: Re: *`how can I see that RFC 5116 is part of TLS 1.2?`* Not wanting to post an answer before closing this dupe, let me kindly remind you that AES-GCM is part of the TLS 1.2 CipherSuite. Check [RFC 5288 – AES Galois Counter Mode (GCM) Cipher Suites for TLS](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5288.txt) to notice the RFC answers your edit (aka sub-Q) on page 1 under section “3.  AES-GCM Cipher Suites” by pointing out that (quote):  `GCM is part of TLS 1.2`. A few lines down it then explicitly mentions and links to RFC 5116. From my point of view, RFCs can’t get any clearer… page 1 is hard to miss.